# How to convert java.io.File to Scala Temporary File in Play 2.6.x

Tags: scala, playframework, temporary-files

I have this code on my project with play 2.5 in spec2 and it's worked fine.
Recently I updated play 2.6.9 and now it does not work anymore.

```
val file = new File(s"$home/the.upload.file4.$fileName")
val pw = new PrintWriter(file)
pw.write(fileContent)
pw.close
val tempFile = TemporaryFile(file)
```

I tried changing it to:

```
val file = new File(s"$home/the.upload.file4.$fileName")
val pw = new PrintWriter(file)
pw.write(fileContent)
pw.close
val tempFile = file.asInstanceOf[TemporaryFile]
```

It compiles but in runtime can't convert java.io.file to a temporary file. The error is:

> [error]  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.File cannot be cast to play.api.libs.Files$TemporaryFile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace

```
val tempFile = file.asInstanceOf[TemporaryFile]
```

with

```
val tempFile = SingletonTemporaryFileCreator.create(file.toPath)
```

and so you can use **TemporaryFileCreator** too,
for more info and another use you can see this
[Interface Files.TemporaryFile](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.9/api/java/play/libs/Files.TemporaryFile.html)

Comment: supporting import statement:
    
import play.api.libs.Files.SingletonTemporaryFileCreator

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to use `TemporaryFileCreator` now to create it: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.9/api/java/play/libs/Files.TemporaryFile.html

Comment: Thank's It helps me but I have some problem with creating an instance from TemporaryFileCreator .